# Angular 4 AmChart

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts

I've Angular project where I'm trying to integrate amCharts. I've html page which looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

and Component which I copied from documentation but for some reason it does not work:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";



am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

@Component({
    selector: 'page',
    styleUrls: ['./page.scss'],
    templateUrl: './page.html'
})
export class PageComponent {
    private chart: am4charts.XYChart;

    constructor(private service: PageService,private zone: NgZone) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

            chart.paddingRight = 20;

            let data = [];
            let visits = 10;
            for (let i = 1; i < 366; i++) {
                visits += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
                data.push({ date: new Date(2018, 0, i), name: "name" + i, value: visits });
            }

            chart.data = data;

            let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
            dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

            let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
            valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
            valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 35;

            let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
            series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
            series.dataFields.valueY = "value";

            series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
            chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

            let scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
            scrollbarX.series.push(series);
            chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

            this.chart = chart;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            if (this.chart) {
                this.chart.dispose();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

But I'm still getting error  `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: {} is not a constructor
TypeError: {} is not a constructor`. `Unhandled Promise rejection: {} is not a constructor ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: {} is not a constructor`. I've tried to debug it and error is caused when I use am4core. As I said I've copied the code from documentation, but it still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is the init method which should be ngOnInit instead of ngAfterViewInit. the rest is fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gu9tkx

the difference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817336/whats-the-difference-between-ngoninit-and-ngafterviewinit-of-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a new angular application with amchart4 without any error following the guide.
Which version of Angular and TypeScript  are you using?
As the guide say, AmChart require TypeScript 2.8 or later.

Comment: That must be it. I've v2.1.5

Comment: @AndriaToria I am using v2.7.3 but it still works fine for me. Have you tried creating graph like this: 
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

    // ... chart code goes here ...

    this.chart = chart;
  });

Answer (score 0):

I apply these lines under "compilerOptions" in "tsconfig.json"

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
"strictNullChecks": false,
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using `ngAfterViewInit()`,`ngOnDestroy()` Lifecycle Hooks, therefore you just need to implement the interface.

```
export class PageComponent implements OnDestroy,AfterViewInit {
```